# Can't get value form input in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form`.

I have a value that comes from my database that I'm using to set the input's value on initial load. When I submit the form I lose the value.

How can I fix this issue?

```js
const FormCV = () => {
 const { register } = useForm();
 const onSubmit = (data) => {alert(JSON.stringify(data))};
 return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     <input
      type="text"
      value={newForm.companyname}
      {...register("companyname")}
     />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you share an executable code in  codesandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `value` prop and set the `value` in react-hook-form's `register` or `defaultProps`.

---

#### Option 1

Set a single value in [register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register).

```js
const { register } = useForm(); // don't need default values set here
<input {...register("companyname",{ value: newForm.companyname })} ...otherProps />
```

---

#### Option 2

Set the values for inputs using [defaultValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform)

```js
const defaultValues = { companyname: newForm.companyname };
const { register } = useForm({ defaultValues });
<input {...register("companyname")} ...otherProps /> // don't need to set the value here
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer.This answer really helpful.